# In the SEDE the data for Meta Stack Exchange is missing

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, meta, data-explorer

In the [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) this site, Meta Stack Exchange, is missing. Can this be added to the weekly data dump, please?